# Pytorch - adding output of hooks to loss function

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I'm loading a model (not written/trained by me) and I've added hooks to some layers of the model using `register_forward_hook`.

My hooks calculate some transformations of the input of layer (which is the output of the previous layer).

The goal is to add the transformations calculated by the hooks to the loss function, so that during fine tune the model will attempt to learn that the output of the transformations should be minimized.

For example:

```py
y1 = None

def hook(module, input):
   y1 = foo(input)

model.some_layer.register_forward_hook(hook)

loss = MSE(...) + L1(y1.detach())
```

Does it make sense to implement it that way? Would it work backpropagation-wise?

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html?highlight=nn%20module#torch.nn.Module.register_forward_hook) and a super impressive tutorial [here](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Enanbhas/blog/forward-hooks-pytorch/#method-3-attach-a-hook) I can say that the forward hook is only called during the `forward()` method call.

That means adding the `global` keyword to your variable as suggested by @Ahmad should work. However, the main concern remains what happens to the value of `y1` when you are training parallelly using GPU. I am not sure if you will get the correct corresponding value of the batch you are training on.

Also, do you really need hooking?
My solution would be to keep a `train` Boolean parameter in the `forward` method - while training pass `True` to this parameter and set it to `False` at the time of testing or inference. In the forward method process the tensors that you get from the layers of interest by calling the processing method (`foo` as mentioned above) directly and return these tensors if the `train` parameter is set to `True`. Define the loss criterion of your choice and pass these "processed tensors" along with the output tensor as parameters to your loss function.

Answer (score 0):

Add the keyword `global` to `y1` calling

```
y1 = None

def hook(module, input):
    global y1
    y1 = foo(input)
```

Also, The forward hook will be executed each time the layer is called during both the `forward pass` and `backward pass`. Since the hooks are called during the `forward pass`, you can calculate `y1` based on the previous layer's output. but, during the `backward pass`, the hooks will still be called, but the `y1` variable may not have the correct value anymore since it was calculated during the `forward pass`. In my opinion, the hook functions should not be used to store values that you need during the `backward pass`. Instead, you can keep the intermediate values in a separate attribute or buffer within the model.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're trying to implement it wouldn't work as expected because of the local variable `y1` within the scope of the `hook` function. This won't allow the outer scope to access the value assigned to `y1` within the hook.

You may want to consider making `y1` an attribute of the model or using a list/dictionary object that can be accessed both inside and outside the hook function. Python's `list` or `dict` objects are mutable, and when passed to a function, the function can modify them.

Here's an example of how you could do this with an attribute:

```py
class YourModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(YourModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.y1 = None

    def forward(self, x):
        # define your forward pass
        pass

    def hook(self, module, input):
        self.y1 = foo(input)

model = YourModel()
model.some_layer.register_forward_hook(model.hook)
```

Or using a list:

```py
y1 = []

def hook(module, input):
   y1.append(foo(input))

model.some_layer.register_forward_hook(hook)
```

As for the other part of your question, yes, it is feasible to add transformations calculated by the hooks to the loss function, and the backpropagation would work as expected as long as you ensure the `y1` tensor keeps its gradient.

In your given example, you've detached `y1` from the computational graph by using `.detach()`. This will prevent the gradient from being backpropagated through it. Therefore, you need to remove `.detach()` from `y1` in your loss function:

```py
loss = MSE(...) + L1(y1)
```

Also be careful to clear out the list or reset the attribute before each forward pass to prevent it from storing unnecessary computation history, which would consume memory and possibly lead to incorrect results.